# Calibre on Ubuntu 18.04 installed in wrong language

Tags: 18.04, calibre

I have installed Calibre via Apps and a momentary lapse means it is now running in Chinese. Removed it, restart, reinstall, no change. Removed it via GUI, then tried in terminal

```
ls /opt/calibre
```

and message file or directory not found.
Do I need reinstall it, but then use instead

```
rm -fr /opt/calibre
```

And after reinstalling use this line from site https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://download.calibre-ebook.com/linux-installer.sh | sudo sh /dev/stdin
```

I am worried about potential incompatibilities.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this file - it's a configuration file for Calibre:

```
/home/[username]/.config/calibre/global.py.json
```

Look for "language" string and change it to "en". Example of my config:

```
"isbndb_com_key": "", 
"language": "en", 
"library_path": "/home/mp/1/ebooks/calibre",
```

Comment: Would some sed magic be a useful adjunct to your answer? A quick look suggested this might do the job: `sed -i_bak 's/"language":.*/"language": "en",/' ~/.config/calibre/global.py.json` although it could be probably tidied up a little...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, Michal. I edited the file in a text editor and changing language to "en" did the trick!